# Nativescript async function returning object promise

Tags: javascript, sqlite, promise, nativescript, nativescript-plugin

I am new to async and await syntax tho. I wrote a function to return the value given by the promise of SQLite query in a native script but the returning value is [object promise] when written to the console.
 Code goes below

```
async function counterChanger(database) {
await database.all("SELECT * FROM pets").then(function (rows) {
    for (row in rows) {
        // console.log(rows[row]);
        counter += 1;//counter is a global variable
    }
    return counter;
}).then(function (counter) {
    counterValue = counter; //counterValue is a global variable initialized to 0
})
console.log("Outside db counterValue is ", counterValue); //meanwhile the console displays the actual value of ounterValue
return counterValue; // the output is [Object promise] instead of the value of counterValue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing async before your inline function. Try this:

```js
async function counterChanger(database) {
    await database.all("SELECT * FROM pets").then(async function(rows) {
        for (row in rows) {
            // console.log(rows[row]);
            counter += 1; //counter is a global variable
        }
        return counter;
    }).then(function(counter) {
        counterValue = counter; //counterValue is a global variable initialized to 0
    })
    console.log("Outside db counterValue is ", counterValue); //meanwhile the console displays the actual value of ounterValue
    return counterValue; // the output is [Object promise] instead of the value of counterValue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole purpose of `async/await` is to avoid the promise chain. You must wrap the await code with `try/catch` block if there are possibilities for errors, and it would always return a `Promise` so your call to `async` function should also use `await` keyword.

```
async function counterChanger(database) {
    try {
       // returning length of returned rows
       return (await database.all("SELECT * FROM pets")).length;
    } catch(e) {
       // just in case if an error thrown for whatever reason, can be handled / logged here
    }
    // would return `0` if there was an error
    return 0;
}

async function updateCounterValue() {
   counterValue = await counterChanger();
}
```